# I still get this annoying error "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Tags: python

I have this python script script and I am trying to make it work but I still get an error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

__author__    = 'irenicus09'
__email__     = 'irenicus09[at]gmail[dot]com'
__license__   = 'BSD'
__version__   = 'BETA'
__date__      = '18/05/2013'
from itertools import permutations
import os 
import sys


"""
##############################  GEN2K  ####################################

                   Automated Word List Generator

> Generates passwords combinations by combining words from wordlist.
> Covers frequently used number patterns used along with words.
> Generates passwords combinations using year/date combo.
> Generates custom user defined value(s) combination with word list.
> Option to auto convert words to upper/lowercase & capitalisation.
> WPA/WPA2 password validation check.
> No external dependencies.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           HINTS:

 * DO NOT USE A GENERAL PURPOSE WORDLIST
 * SUPPLIED WORDLIST MUST ONLY CONTAIN KNOWN FACTS ABOUT TARGET
   E.G NAMES, ADDRESS, FAVORITE ARTIST, PLACE, EVENT, ETC.
 * TRY TO KEEP WORDLIST AT A MINIMUM, DON'T INCLUDE TOO MUCH DETAILS
 * THE FINAL GENERATED WORD LIST CAN GET EXTREMELY LARGE!

###########################################################################
"""


def help():
    print """


        ######   ######## ##    ##  #######  ##    ##
       ##    ##  ##       ###   ## ##     ## ##   ##
       ##        ##       ####  ##        ## ##  ##
       ##   #### ######   ## ## ##  #######  #####
       ##    ##  ##       ##  #### ##        ##  ##
       ##    ##  ##       ##   ### ##        ##   ##
        ######   ######## ##    ## ######### ##    ##  %s

        ======= Automated Word List Generator =======

               Copyright (C) irenicus09 2013


   USAGE: ./gen2k.py -w <wordlist> -o <output> [options]

   [ -c ] Enable word combination among the words in wordlist.

   [ -d ] Custom comma separated values to combine with wordlist.

   [ -e ] Enable wpa/wpa2 fitness check for generated passwords.

   [ -h ] Prints this help.

   [ -n ] Enable frequently used number combination with wordlist.

   [ -o ] Output filename.

   [ -w ] Path to word list file.
          Wordlist must contain info related to Target.

   [ -y ] Enable year combination with wordlist.

   [ -z ] Enable conversion of words to upper & lower case letters.

          Note: Conversion to upper/lowercase & capitalisation
          takes place before other modes are applied to the original list.

   """ % __version__




def main():

    if exist('-h'):
        help()
        sys.exit(0)

    if not (exist('-w') or exist('-o')):
        help()
        sys.exit(1)

    master_list = load_words(find('-w')) # List supplied by user

    data = [] # Final wordlist
    temp = [] # Temporary wordlist

    if exist('-z'):
        master_list = gen_case(master_list)
        data = master_list

    if exist('-c'):
        temp = gen_word_combo(master_list)
        data = list(set(temp+data))

    if exist('-n'):
        temp = gen_numbers(master_list)
        data = list(set(temp+data))

    if exist('-y'):
        temp = gen_year(master_list)
        data = list(set(temp+data))

    if exist('-d'):
        try:
            custom_values = find('-d').split(',')
        except (AttributeError):
            print '[!] Are you kidding me with no values?'
            sys.exit(1)

        temp = gen_custom(master_list, custom_values)
        data = list(set(temp+data))

    if exist('-e'):
        data = wpa_validation_check(data)

    write_file(find('-o'), data)

    print '[*] Total words generated: %d' % (len(data))

    sys.exit(0)


def merge_list(temp_list=[], final_list=[]):
    """
   Merges contents from temp_list (1st param) with final_list (2nd param)
   """
    for word in temp_list:
        if word not in final_list:
            final_list.append(word)


def load_words(path_to_file):
    """
   Function to fetch all possible words.
   """
    data = []

    try:
        handle = open(path_to_file, 'r')
        temp_list = handle.readlines()
        handle.close()

    except(BaseException):
        print '[!] Error occured while reading wordlist.'
        sys.exit(1)

    for word in temp_list:
        word = word.strip()
        if word != '':
            data.append(word)

    return data



def write_file(path_to_file, data=[]):
    """
   Writing to specified file.
   """
    try:
        handle = open(path_to_file, 'wb+')

        for word in data:
            handle.write(word+'\n')

        handle.close()
    except(BaseException):
        print '[!] Error occured while writing to file.'
        sys.exit(1)



def gen_case(words=[]):
    """
   Function to change words to Upper & Lower case.
   """
    custom_list = []

    for x in words:
        custom_list.append(x.lower())
        custom_list.append(x.capitalize())
        custom_list.append(x.upper())

    return list(set(custom_list))



def gen_numbers(words=[]):
    """
   Function to mix words with commonly used numbers patterns.
   """
    word_list = []

    if len(words) <= 0:
        return word_list

    num_list = ['0', '01', '012', '0123', '01234', '012345', '0123456', '01234567', '012345678', '0123456789',
    '1', '12', '123', '1234','12345', '123456','1234567','12345678','123456789', '1234567890', '9876543210',
    '987654321', '87654321', '7654321', '654321', '54321', '4321', '321', '21']

    for word in words:
        for num in num_list:
            word_list.append((word+num))
            word_list.append((num+word))

    return word_list




def gen_year(words=[]):
    """
   Function to mix auto generated year with words from wordlist.

   Hint: Date of birth & special dates are often
         combined with certain words to form
         passwords.
   """
    word_list = []

    if len(words) <= 0:
        return word_list

    # Double digit dates
    start = 1
    while(start <= 99):
        for word in words:
            word_list.append(word + str("%02d") % (start))
            word_list.append(str("%02d") % start + word)
        start += 1

    # Four digit dates
    start = 1900
    while (start <= 2020):
        for word in words:
            word_list.append(word+str(start))
            word_list.append(str(start)+word)
        start += 1

    return word_list




def gen_word_combo(words=[]):
    """
   Function to mix multiple words from given list.
   """
    word_list = []

    if len(words) <= 1:
        return word_list
 for n in range(1, len(words)+1):
 for perm in permutations(xlist, n):
     word_list.append( "".join(perm) )

    return word_list




def gen_custom(words=[], data=[]):
    """
   Funtion to combine user defined input with wordlist.

   > Takes a comma separated list via cmdline as values.
   """
    word_list = []

    if (len(words) <= 0 or len(data) <= 0):
        return word_list

    for item in data:
        for word in words:
            word_list.append(item+word)
            word_list.append(word+item)

    return word_list



def wpa_validation_check(words=[]):
    """
   Function to optimise wordlist for wpa cracking

   > Removes Duplicates.
   > Removes passwords < 8 or > 63 characters in length.
   """
    custom_list =  list(set(words))
    custom_list = [x for x in custom_list if not (len(x) < 8 or len(x) > 63)]

    return custom_list


# S3my0n's argument parsers, thx brah :)
def find(flag):
    try:
        a = sys.argv[sys.argv.index(flag)+1]
    except (IndexError, ValueError):
        return None
    else:
        return a

def exist(flag):
    if flag in sys.argv[1:]:
        return True
    else:
        return False








if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You should *definately* look into the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html) module which is in the python standard library.  You don't have to reinvent the wheel to parse your arguments or make your help message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def gen_word_combo(words=[]):
    """
   Function to mix multiple words from given list.
   """
    word_list = []

    if len(words) <= 1:
        return word_list
 for n in range(1, len(words)+1):
 for perm in permutations(xlist, n):
     word_list.append( "".join(perm) )

    return word_list
```

This code is incorrectly indented.

```
def gen_word_combo(words=[]):
    """
   Function to mix multiple words from given list.
   """
    word_list = []

    if len(words) <= 1:
        return word_list
    for n in range(1, len(words)+1):
        for perm in permutations(xlist, n):
            word_list.append( "".join(perm) )

    return word_list
```

Also, you'll probably want to change `xlist` there, since that variable doesn't exist anywhere else in the code.

Comment: now I am facing this problem Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gen2k.py", line 332, in <module>
    main()
  File "gen2k.py", line 106, in main
    temp = gen_word_combo(master_list)
  File "gen2k.py", line 268, in gen_word_combo
    for perm in permutations(xlist, n):
NameError: global name 'xlist' is not defined

Comment: Like I already said in my answer, `xlist` doesn't exist. I suggest changing it to something that does exist. (I don't know what to change it to, since I didn't write this code and I don't know what it's supposed to be doing. Since you _did_ write this code, you should have a better idea than me)

Answer (score 0):

Python uses space to determine code blocks

```
def definiton_name():
    this = " 4 spaces in from a def block, which is usually the standard (or a single tab, and ive even seen 2 spaces before..)"
    for item in "under a loop of some sort":
        print(1, "this is the inside of a for block")
   print(2,"this line is outside the For block, but it is not in line with any other block, so this line is broken")
```

the `print(2,` line is NOT part of the `for` block, so it isnt under the `print(1,` line HOWEVER its not under the `this=` line either, so interpreter will trip out and not know whats going on, due to indentions

Comment: thank you alot man I love you really helped me  it is working properly